# Hosting codeigniter on Hostinger

Tags: codeigniter, hosting, webhooks, autodeploy

I was currently host codeigniter on hostinger by using the Git webhook. It provide me the continuous development. which mean the hostinger will listen to any push from git and run it own deployment script to help me host the site.

But the issue is it not run the update and serve command so that i have to access to ssh every single time i make changes with my project and run "composer update" and "php spark serve" to keep the site on.

is there any solution for automatic process ?

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.